# What is this usage of letters for centuries?

Tags: nombres, indications-de-temps

I came about the following:

> Au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle

Is XX representing some unknown value for the century? How do you know what it is? Does it mean something else entirely?

Comment: I edited your question to something a little better suited for the site and voted to reopen it. If it differs too much from what you meant, feel free to edit further.

Comment: @Kareen  The use of Roman numerals is general knowledge and have nothing particular to the French language. They are used for dates and yeafrs in a lot of European countries. English uses them a lot as well, see relevant article in Wikipedia for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In French, centuries are usually indicated with [roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals). In this case, XX is 20. “*XX<sup>e</sup> siècle*” means “20<sup>th</sup> century”.